# How to get a subobject out of JSON using jq, keeping final key in the result without Bash processing?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm writing a Bash function to get a portion of a JSON object. The API for the function is:

```
GetSubobject()
{
   local Filter="$1"    # Filter is of the form .<key>.<key> ... .<key>
   local File="$2"      # File is the JSON to get the subobject

   # Code to get subobject using jq
   # ...
}
```

To illustrate what I mean by a subobject, consider the Bash function call:

```
GetSubobject .b.x.y example.json
```

where the file example.json contains:

```
{
   "a": { "p": 1, "q": 2 },
   "b":
   {
      "x":
      {
          "y": { "j": true, "k": [1,2,3] },
          "z": [4,5,6]
      }
   }
}
```

The result from the function call would be emitted to stdout:

```
{
  "y": {
    "j": true,
    "k": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the code `jq -r "$Filter" "$File"` would not give the desired answer. It would give:

```
{ "j": true, "k": [1,2,3] }
```

Please note that the answer I'm looking for needs to be something I can use in the Bash function API above. So, the answer should use the Filter and File variables as show above and not be specific to the example above.

I have come up with a solution; however, it relies on Bash to do part of the job. I am hoping that the solution can be pure jq without reliance on Bash processing.

```
#!/bin/bash

GetSubobject()
{
   local Filter="$1"
   local File="$2"

   # General case: separate:
   #    .<key1>.<key2> ... .<keyN-1>.<keyN>
   # into:
   #   Prefix=.<key1>.<key2> ... .<keyN-1>
   #   Suffix=<keyN>
   local Suffix="${Filter##*.}"
   local Prefix="${Filter%.$Suffix}"

   # Edge case: where Filter = .<key>
   # Set:
   #    Prefix=.
   #    Suffix=<key>
   if [[ -z $Prefix ]]; then
      Prefix='.'
      Suffix="${Filter#.}"
   fi

   jq -r "$Prefix|to_entries|map(select(.key==\"$Suffix\"))|from_entries" "$File"
}

GetSubobject "$@"
```

How would I complete the above Bash function using jq to obtain the desired result, hopefully in a less brute-force way that takes advantage of jq's capabilities without having to do pre-processing in Bash?

Comment: What's the logical relationship between your filter expressions and your desired output?

I don't understand why you want the output of `'.b.x.y'` to be what `jq` outputs on `'.b.x'`.

Do you always just want to ignore the final filter of the `jq` expression?  What do you do when the input is just `.`?

Comment: So, maybe it's not a 'subobject' but a 'superobject'?  You want to match the parent of whatever's matched by the `jq` expression?

Comment: The issue is that the final part of the Filter passed to the Bash function is the key that must be preserved in the output. The parent key of the Filter would over-select and give not just y, but also z. I don't have the proper terminology for what I want, but I hoped the example will be useful.

Comment: Your example shows '.b.x.y' selecting '.b.x' (you show z in the desired output), is that a mistake?  I think I'm missing something, I'll play with your example locally to see if I can follow better.

Comment: Ah, yes... it is.  I'll correct it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat further simplifying the `jq` part but with the same general constraints as JawguyChooser's answer, how about the much simpler Bash function

```
GetSubject () {
    local newroot=${1##*.}
    jq -r "{$newroot: $1}" "$2"
}
```

I may be overlooking some nuances of your more-complex Bash processing, but this seems to work for the example you provided.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that you could construct an object as you've shown. The code can be further reduced to a single line, including quotes to allow for non-alphanumeric keys: `jq -r "{\"${1##*.}\": \"$1\"}" "$2""`

Comment: Indeed it can; and I'd probably do that in my own code. I thought the temporary variable made the exposition slightly clearer, but other than that, there's obviously no need for it.

Comment: While peak's solution provides a pure jq solution, it has the disadvantage of being hard to understand for maintenance programmers that might later look at the code. Your solution requires some minimal Bash processing (better than my OP), so for the sheer simplicity of your approach, I'm going to mark this as the accepted solution. Again, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, it doesn't seem possible to me to do it "pure jq" having read the docs (and being a regular `jq` user myself). The closest I could come to helping here was to simplify the `jq` part itself:

```
jq -r "$Prefix| { $Suffix }" "$File"
```

This has the same behavior as your example (on this limited set of cases):

```
GetSubobject '.b.x.y' example.json
{
  "y": {
    "j": true,
    "k": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

This is really a case of metaprogramming, you want to programmatically operate on a `jq` program.  Well, it makes sense (to me) that `jq` takes its program as input but doesn't allow you to alter the program itself.  bash seems like an appropriate choice for doing the metaprogramming here: to convert a `jq` program into another one and then run `jq` using that.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe the OP means *additional external processing* is problematic and that this limited use of Bash features to obtain their result is just fine. But I can obviously only speculate.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to do as little as possible in `bash`, then maybe the following bash function will fill the bill:

```
function GetSubobject {
   local Filter="$1"    # Filter is of the form .<key>.<key> ... .<key>
   local File="$2"      # File is the JSON to get the subobject
   jq  '(null|path('"$Filter"')) as $path
        | {($path[-1]): '"$Filter"'}' "$File"
}
```

An alternative would be to pass `$Filter` in as a string (e.g. --arg filter "$Filter"), have jq do the parsing, and then use `getpath`.

It would of course be simplest if GetSubobject could be called with the path separated from the field of interest, like this:

```
GetSubobject .b.x y filename
```

Comment: As always, your replies are informative and helpful in learning jq. I've upvoted your answer because of that. However, the expression that tripleee provided is easier for maintenance programmers to understand, so I'll mark that as the solution. Many thanks for your time in teaching us all jq!